# Cannot find module angular2/modal

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I'm working with angular2 version beta15
I want to use Modal of angular2/Modal
but I note that I have not classes that I need to use it as Modal ,ModalConfig

Answer (score 0):

[This Github post](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/issues/20) explains how to get Modal for Angular 2. Once you run `npm install angular2-modal --save` you should have a folder called `angular2-modal` which can be imported into your code like this:

```
import {Modal, ModalConfig} from 'angular2-modal';
```